# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS | Canon MF8080CW Not Printing

Tags: printing, canon

I'm running Ubuntu on a 64-bit computer. I downloaded the file from the official Canon website and installed the 3 drivers for Debian x64. Now whenever I go to settings and look for a printer there's only MF8000C and MF8000C-2. I tried to print through both of these options but nothing printed. I tried restarting the printer and it still didn't work after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so perhaps the best way to install the linux package for this is to go here

http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100924010.html for the 3.5 version of the UFR driver that was updated 8th Feb 2018.

Download and SAVE what will be **linux-UFRII-drv-v350-uken.tar.gz** and doing it this way, means the install script should do things for you.

So copy each line below; line by line; paste into a terminal; hit the ENTER key; move to next line

```
cd Downloads

tar -zxvf linux-UFRII-drv-v350-uken.tar.gz

cd linux-UFRII-drv-v350-uken

sudo ./install.sh
```

- best before running the above, to delete any existing icons from the
  **PRINTERS** folder; (as you say they do not work);
- If you only report "MF8000C and MF8000C-2", I doubt the system has
  used the Canon drivers; it has used some "near-fit" from its default;
- (to use a printer, you need to 1) install drivers and 2) register the
  printer; 2) may **NOT** necessarily follow from 1)

so the install script in the above is **GOOD** because Canon ensure you go from 1) to 2) and allocate the correct ppd file to the printer

Comment: This worked to solve the driver problem, but you also have to open up the canon app from the application menu and there was also a manual setup involved to get the wireless printer working. For those who are also having this problem, the protocol is lpd.